# Use Variables and show in content

Tags: confluence

I've created a confluence wiki, which contains content for 3 products.

Currently, I have some specific manuals for this product variants and some manuals, which are 90% percent similar.

My structure looks like this:

Space > product homepage > manuals

Is there any chance to use one document and hide/show product specific context? For example, if the user comes from the product homepage 'Testproduct', I would show specific content for this product and also set a variable in the content which shows the name of the product (e.g. 'Welcome to *Testproduct*').

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind to use a commercial add-on then the [projectdoc Toolbox](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/1YEp) may provide tools for your information architecture requirements.

The [Section Macro](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/ugNk) allows to show/hide dependent on [space properties](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/jwNk). That would imply that you use a space per product and configure the product specifics via space properties.

You could use the [Remote Control feature](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/MgFYB) in case you want to configure the rendering of the page based on request parameters. Note that this would only control the rendering of one request. If the user clicks on a link on this page, the request properties from the original request would be lost. The use case for this feature is to configure the rendering of a page when used from outside of Confluence -- for instance to show documentation for error codes. But it may also be used from within using the [Wiki Link Macro](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/xQNk).

You could also use the [impersonator or live template](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/DgDUBg). In this case you would configure the layout of your page (with some content that is common for all of your products) and then use transclusion to use this layout in your product spaces.

We use our product to provide documentation for our plugins for [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/). You can see examples on our website:

- [Buildmetadata Maven Plugin](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BMMP)
- [smartics JBoss Maven Plugin](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/MQAuAQ)
- [Apptools Maven Plugin](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/twF8Bg)
- [Doctype Maven Plugin](https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/x/zgDqAw)

Please note that these products are independent of each other and therefore do not require the content reuse of your use cases. I added the examples to show how we use the projectdoc Toolbox, especially space properties, for our products.

And finally I have to point out that I am one of the authors of the projectdoc Toolbox. So I am probably biased ... ;)

The projectdoc Toolbox is [available on the Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/1212629).